# Toolbar logo not clickable but still functioning as drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The burger drawer functioning well, however the toolbar logo didnt work when i click it. I checked everyting however i didnt find whats wrong. i tried working it on clean acvitivity and the logo and drawer really works. the drawer only works only when i slide it to the right. please really appreciate it thank you for helping.

heres my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bordergreen4"
    tools:context=".duashome"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">




    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bordergreen4"
        tools:context=".home">


       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/duasupperlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:logo="@drawable/ic_baseline_dehaze_24"
               android:id="@+id/toolbar">
           </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </LinearLayout>

       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/duasupperlayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2E856E"
            android:fontFamily="@font/hallington"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="List of Duas"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp">


        </TextView>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/duaslowerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
    
       <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/duaslowerlayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/duasupperlayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Dua Tawassul">

                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Dua Kumayl">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Dua Azumal Bala">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="sdsds">
                </Button>




            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        
        
    </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and java

```
package com.example.munajat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class duashome extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duashome);

        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //navdrawermenu

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making the `NavigationView` last in the `DrawerLayout` and see if it works...

Comment: So to be clear your toolbar has both `burger navigation icon` and `logo icon` side by side? And you want the drawer to work when you click either of them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **Toolbar** to the ActionBarDrawerToggle.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```